# Value changed to null in ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Value changed to null in ajax after updating the shipping city value from text field. I don't known what is the problem.. please help me Friends.

my php code:

```
 public function updateshippingcity() {

  if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
   {
      $json['new_shipping_city'] = $this->request->post['shipping_city'];


     $this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "order SET shipping_city = '" . $this->db->escape($this->request->post['shipping_city']) . "' WHERE order_id = '" . (int)$this->request->get['order_id'] . "'");


     $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
  }
```

}

my ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#update-shipping-city").click(function() {
    var name_val = $('input[name="new_shipping_city"]').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/updateshippingcity&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            shipping_city: name_val
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#update-shipping-city').attr('disabled', true);
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#update-shipping-city').attr('disabled', false);
        },
        success: function(json) {

        }
    });
    alert("shipping city has changed");
});
```

my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input  name="new_shipping_city" value="<?php echo $shipping_city; ?>"></input>
    <button id="update-shipping-city" > update </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: WHAT??? `<a id="update-shipping-city" class="button" style="cursor: pointer;"><?php echo 'change shipping city'; ?></a>` are you echoing the text for ???

Comment: @RiggsFolly its only visible in admin dashboards. not in public website. anyway thanks for the information :)

Comment: That really should make no difference.

Comment: Visible to admins only or not, you should always follow best security practices when developing an application.  Using prepared statements in an application is not a very hard thing to do.

Comment: @RiggsFolly that <a> tag only for clicking usage.. i need to change the value of the $shipping_city through ajax. that i tried here.. but after updating ajax sends null value to db :(

Comment: And WHY after doing an AJAX call to get data from the server are you then reloading the page?? Totally negating the point of the AJAX call ???

Comment: @Taplar i don't know how to change it?

Comment: I thought what RiggsFolly was questioning with that echo, was that you were echoing a static string, not a variable.  So it could have just been in the markup without the echo.

Comment: @Taplar Absolutely correct

Comment: RiggsFolly linked the prepared statements link in his one comment at the end

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm used reloading for page refresh. is that not required?

Comment: The main point of AJAX is to amend the page dynamically without having to refresh the page

Comment: @RiggsFolly i'm a beginner thanks for the information. Now i need the solution for my problem :(

Comment: Please anyone give me a answer for my prblm.. :(

Comment: You ahve not given us enough code. Expand the `my html code:` code so we can see what happens when the page gets reloaded. That is where it should be picking up the chnaged database so we need to see what is going on in there

Comment: I had updated my question, i want to update the $shipping_city after clicking the update button in ajax

Comment: do you get errors somewhere?

Comment: @AmrAly      i got no errors but value is updated as null

Comment: when you inspect the input element before submitting the button does it show you the correct value?

Comment: there no  data is printed in php so how value will be returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had achieved finally  by post method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#update-shipping-city").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var scity_val = $('input[name="new_shipping_city"]').val();
        $.post("index.php?route=sale/order/updateshippingcity&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&order_id=<?php echo $order_id; ?>", {
            shipping_city: scity_val
        }, function(data, status) {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
        });
    });
});
```

Finally, my problem cleared. thank guys for contributing on my question :)